# Android app using PHP and MySQL - Dreamweaver shows root error

Tags: php, android, mysql, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

I am making an android app using php and mysql. I am using Dreamweaver while making this using phonegap. If I create this using index.html file. It works fine, But I dont want to use .html extension. I want to use .php. Where I can fetch my data form MYSQL and display my results after logged in into my app. Please share your views that how can I use index.php and other .php files in it.

> I am having this error while using index.php

[image: I am having this error while using index.php]

Comment: simple change the editor

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you have to set the index page to make a HTTP request.

http://phonegap.com/about/faq/

> Q: Can you use PHP/ASP/JSF/Java/.NET with PhoneGap?
>
> A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
>   However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web
>   Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in
>   any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access
>   existing business processes while the device is connected to the
>   Internet.

Comment: If I dont't use phone gap and make a index.php with jqury.Mobile(local). It shows error again.